# Unity Firebase C# - How to post to database from android apk instead of editor?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase in my unity project. I have a function that posts a json to the database:

```
public void PostToDatabase(){
        //Convert both objects to json files [string]
        Player1Json = ConvertToJson(Player1Data);
        Player2Json = ConvertToJson(Player2Data);

        if (Data.HostPlayer)  {
            FBDatabase.GetReference("GameID:" + Data.gameID.ToString()).Child("WinVal").SetValueAsync(win);
            FBDatabase.GetReference("GameID:" + Data.gameID.ToString()).Child("PlayersConnected").SetValueAsync(playersConnected);
            FBDatabase.GetReference("GameID:" + Data.gameID.ToString()).Child("Player1").SetRawJsonValueAsync(Player1Json);

        }
        else if(Data.ClientPlayer) {
            FBDatabase.GetReference("GameID:" + Data.gameID.ToString()).Child("WinVal").SetValueAsync(win);
            FBDatabase.GetReference("GameID:" + Data.gameID.ToString()).Child("PlayersConnected").SetValueAsync(playersConnected);
            FBDatabase.GetReference("GameID:" + Data.gameID.ToString()).Child("Player2").SetRawJsonValueAsync(Player2Json);
        }
        UpdateFromDatabase();
    }
```

This works fine in the editor. However, when I build the project to windows, android, etc. the data never posts because database is never ready to use(or something). How do I make it so I can post and update data from the database on an android apk or a unity build on windows the same way it works in the editor??

I've been struggling for weeks with this and can't find a solution anywhere. Here is the start function:

```
void Start(){
        // Set this before calling into the realtime database.
        FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://MY-PROJECT.firebaseio.com/");
        FBDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance;


        //Initialize both players' data [Data]
        Player1Data = new Data();
        Player2Data = new Data();

        //Increment how many players are connected [int]
        playersConnected++;
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Here is what log cat is saying:
[image: LogCatErrors]

**UPDATE 2**
I downloaded Android Studio and tried to run the gradle project and received these errors:

05/15 13:10:03: Launching 'launcher' on motorola moto g(6) play.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.DefaultCompany.RtsDefense/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.DefaultCompany.RtsDefense/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.DefaultCompany.RtsDefense/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.DefaultCompany.RtsDefense/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup
Make sure you've followed each step of Android Setup for Firebase.

From what I can understand, if it works in the Editor, then it should work in Android unless:
 1. The device isn't connected to the Internet.
 2. Setup of Firebase isn't properly done.

Note: Please put the Logs of your device when you try to call this function. What happens? Any error/crashes or anything else.

Comment: I can't even log anything because that function is only called when i press a  button. But the button is only interactable when Firebase checks all its dependencies, and for some reason when I build the game, the button is never interactable.

Comment: It would help if you could provide any related errors. The easiest way to capture these in Unity (in my opinion) is to use the LogCat plugin: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.android-logcat@0.1/manual/index.html. You may want to make sure you're using ContinueWithOnMainThread if you're currently using ContinueWith, that your Android device supports play services (you have the google play store), and that you have a google-services.json file included and the bundle id in it matches your app's bundle id.

Comment: Are you using the latest? (6.14: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity)

Comment: I did a brief search and found this very looking bug on the issues page: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/676. It could be worth adding to it or creating a new bug. I do notice that both samples seem to have temporary package id's (my.package.id in the bug I linked, "https://MY-PROJECT.firebaseio.com/" in your issue), are you purposefully obfuscating your database URL or is that a copy/paste issue?

Comment: (also note that you don't need to call SetEditorDatabaseUrl - especially if you only have one database)

Comment: Well that shouldn't happen. Would you mind trying to force resolve dependencies? Go to the following place in the menu: Assets>External Dependency Manager>Android Resolver>Force Resolve

Comment: @PatrickMartin same result, nothing new happened and with the same error

Comment: It may be easier to debug this if you posted an issue, but would you mind posting the Manifest that was generated? Also any relevant logs in the Unity editor.

Comment: I'm guessing that there might be some issue in generating the Android manifest if it can't find the launcher activity?

Comment: @PatrickMartin here is the [manifest](https://i.imgur.com/H3gUF66.png)

Comment: I would actually need to see the final merged Manifest. You can get this by looking in the `Temp/` directory if you've recently done an Android build or by exporting your Android project from the build window. Mostly I want to make sure that the launcher intent was created. If it isn't, we'd need to do more debugging along that route: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER